# How does Delphi XE2 Firemonkey's Align property set to alScale affect the coordinate system?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

How does Delphi XE2 Firemonkey's Align property set to alScale affect the coordinate system?

I am looking at Firemonkey's canvas drawing capabilities and came across problems with the coordinates system when a component's Align property is set to alScale. The following demonstration program (a FM HD application) illustrates the problem. 
Compile and run the sample code, draw a couple of lines, then change the form's size for the weirdness to begin. The lines do not appear at the expected locations.

Any suggestions and explanations would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

The main form (LineDrawFormUnit.pas):

```
unit LineDrawFormUnit;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Objects;

type
  TLineDrawForm = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImageControl;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    lX: TLabel;
    lY: TLabel;
    { These event handlers are set in the IDE's object inspector }
    procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);

    { This event handler is set/unset with the MouseDown and MouseUp events to capture mouse moves when drawing }
    procedure ImageControl1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  private
    FSaveBitmap: TBitmap;
    p1, p2: TPointF;    { Start and end points of lines to draw }
  end;

var
  LineDrawForm: TLineDrawForm;

implementation
{$R *.fmx}

procedure TLineDrawForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Image1.Bitmap.Create(Round(Image1.Width), Round(Image1.Height));
end;

procedure TLineDrawForm.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
  p1.X := X;
  p1.Y := Y;
  lX.Text := FloatToStr(X);
  lY.Text := FloatToStr(Y);
  FSaveBitmap := TBitmap.Create(Image1.Bitmap.Width, Image1.Bitmap.Height);
  FSaveBitmap.Assign(Image1.Bitmap); { Save the current canvas as bitmap }
  Image1.OnMouseMove := ImageControl1MouseMove; { Activate the MouseMove event handler}
end;

procedure TLineDrawForm.ImageControl1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  p2.X := X;
  p2.Y := Y;
  lX.Text := FloatToStr(X);
  lY.Text := FloatToStr(Y);
  Image1.Bitmap.Assign(FSaveBitmap);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := claGray;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.StrokeThickness := 0.5;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(p1, p2, 1.0);
  finally
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
    Image1.Bitmap.BitmapChanged;
  end;
end;

procedure TLineDrawForm.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Single);
begin
  p2.X := X;
  p2.Y := Y;
  lX.Text := FloatToStr(X);
  lY.Text := FloatToStr(Y);
  Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.Stroke.Color := claBlack;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.StrokeThickness := 2;
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(P1, P2, 1.0);
  finally
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
    Image1.Bitmap.BitmapChanged;
  end;

  (Sender as TControl).OnMouseMove := nil;
  if FSaveBitmap <> nil then
    FSaveBitmap.Free;

end;

end.
```

The FMX file (LineDrawFormUnit.fmx):

```
object LineDrawForm: TLineDrawForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Polygon Form'
  ClientHeight = 513
  ClientWidth = 650
  Visible = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  StyleLookup = 'backgroundstyle'
  object Image1: TImageControl
    Align = alScale
    Position.Point = '(18,21)'
    Width = 620.000000000000000000
    Height = 452.000000000000000000
    OnMouseDown = Image1MouseDown
    OnMouseUp = Image1MouseUp
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Align = alBottom
    Position.Point = '(0,480)'
    Width = 650.000000000000000000
    Height = 33.000000000000000000
    TabOrder = 2
    object Label1: TLabel
      Position.Point = '(16,8)'
      Width = 25.000000000000000000
      Height = 15.000000000000000000
      TabOrder = 1
      Text = 'X:'
    end
    object Label2: TLabel
      Position.Point = '(384,8)'
      Width = 25.000000000000000000
      Height = 15.000000000000000000
      TabOrder = 2
      Text = 'Y:'
    end
    object lX: TLabel
      Position.Point = '(32,8)'
      Width = 313.000000000000000000
      Height = 15.000000000000000000
      TabOrder = 3
      Text = '0'
    end
    object lY: TLabel
      Position.Point = '(424,8)'
      Width = 209.000000000000000000
      Height = 15.000000000000000000
      TabOrder = 4
      Text = '0'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: P.S. I originally had forgotten to get rid of the unused PolygonUnit in the interface Uses clause, now corrected.

Comment: Image1.Bitmap is not scaled up when Image1 is enlarged with the form. However, it is reduced in size when Image1 is shrunk with the form, and again expanded up to original size when the form is expanded. Setting an OnResize handler for the form allows adjusting size of Image1.Bitmap to match its container, but it is cleared. The bitmap shrinks and grows back to its original size when the form's size is reduced and expanded. There must be a non-lossy way to resize TBitmap without clearing its content. Otherwise, one would have to resort to using the TBitmap.ScanLine function.

Comment: P.S. Enlarging a bitmap would make it grainy, so it makes sense that bitmap shrinks and returns to its original size and not larger. Still need to figure out how it is internally accomplished by the framework.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the `Align` property (it's also reproducible with `alClient`, by the way). The problem is caused by the fact that the image control is resized but its bitmap is not, therefore it scales. When creating FSaveBitmap you should create it with the size of the image control, not its internal bitmap (otherwise you're not reflecting the changed size of the control and cause scaling).

Comment: Thanks TOndrej. I will try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The align property affects the **TShapes** descendants, the **TControl** etc but not the content of a Bitmap.

You seem to buffer some custom drawings on a TBitmap, then to assign it to a control.
FMX won't be able to realign the custom drawings because they are not encapsulated in an alignable class (it's just some pixels).

You can redraw the "buffer" when the control is resized and reassign it to its "host" to adapt the drawings to your wishes. Or maybe don't free the "buffered drawings" and transform it/reassign it when the form is resized.

But a better way to do this, which would match to how FMX HD is intended to be used, is to use the shape system, the alignment will be automatic. 
So instead of drawing a line, create a TLine inside the parent object and layer the alignement of this new line according to the parent control.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am now using a similar approach using a TPath object. It made life much easier. Also, the MouseDown events already check for point-in-polygon very efficiently. The easiest way to create Data for the path object I found was drawing the shapes in Illustrator/InkScape, saving the file in SVG format and extracting the relevant path information from the fie with a text-editor. I really wish FireMonkey had better documentation.